# iptables: redirect трафика на другой порт

Tags: linux, iptables

Добрый день.
Суть вопроса: нужно перенаправить трафик от одного конкретного хоста с одного порта на другой (форвардить трафик куда-то дальше не нужно, нужно только принять его именно от этого хоста на нестандартном порту). Я прописал правило:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth2.2 -p udp --src MY.SOURCE.IP.ADDRESS --dport 162 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 10150
```

но когда я встаю tcpdump-ом посмотреть, что приходит на порт 10150, то ничего не вижу:

```
tcpdump -i any port 10150
```

Список правил таблицы nat:

```
iptables -t nat -L -v -n --line-numbers
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 35073 packets, 5126K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               
destination
1       56  7112 REDIRECT   udp  --  eth2.2 *       172.21.10.2          0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:162 redir ports 10150

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 289K packets, 53M bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 289K packets, 53M bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Причем видно, что через правило редиректа какие-то пакеты проходят...

Список правил таблицы filter:

```
iptables -L -v -n --line-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1      10G 4374G ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2    81806   10M ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
3    1945K  200M ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
4        0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:514
5        0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:49
6    1163K   56M ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:49
7    17610  778K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:249
8        0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:249
9      491 28508 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22
10    482K   27M ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpts:10099:10200
11   1382K  107M ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:162
12       0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:514
13   14437 5626K ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:10113
14       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:514
15       0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:10150
16    3187  250K REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 2565K packets, 825M bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Таблица raw

```
iptables -t raw -L -n
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59785/discussion-on-question-by---iptables-redirect---).